List Managed Identities that have access to the ExchangeOnline.ManageAsApp API
I have a couple of Azure Automation runbooks that update Dynamic Distribution Lists. To make this work, I gave the Azure Automation System-Assigned Managed Identity permissions to access and make changes to Exchange Online using steps here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-exo-powershell-managed-identity?view=exchange-ps#step-4-grant-the-exchangemanageasapp-api-permission-for-the-managed-identity-to-call-exchange-online. These runbooks work as designed.
I'm in the process of developing more automation using a separate Automation account and Managed Identity. I want to confirm the Managed Identities that have access to Exchange Online. How can I list which Managed Identities have access to Exchange Online? I've tried Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedTo, but this only lists Entra ID Enterprise and Registered Apps, not Exchange Online.
Similarly, is there a way to list all permissions and roles assigned to an Azure Automation Managed Identity? I granted a new Managed Identity the User Management role in Entra ID, but this does not show up under the Managed Identity, but the Managed Identity is listed under the individual Roles.

@TylerH, why did you edit the "Thank you for your time" out of my post? Did I violate a posting rule?

Yes, salutations are not allowed in Stack Exchange posts because they are noise. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it for more information.

Got it. I would show my appreciation for educating me, but I don't want you to remove it... :P

I enabled system managed identity for the Automation account and granted Exchange API permissions:
$AppRoleID = "dc50a0fb-09a3-484d-be87-e023b12c6440"
$ResourceID = (Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'").Id
$MI_ID = "ManagedIdentityServicePrincipalObjID"

New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $MI_ID -PrincipalId $MI_ID -AppRoleId $AppRoleID -ResourceId $ResourceID



To get the permissions assigned to managed identity, make use of below command:
Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId ManagedIdentityServicePrincipalObjID | select -Property Id, AppRoleId, PrincipalDisplayName


To list the managed identities with Exchange API permissions/Office 365 Exchange Online permissions, make use of below code:
# Define the Office 365 Exchange Online ResourceId  
$ExchangeOnlineResourceId = (Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'").Id

# Retrieve all managed identities  
$ManagedIdentities = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "ServicePrincipalType eq 'ManagedIdentity'"

# Iterate over each managed identity  
foreach ($ManagedIdentity in $ManagedIdentities) {  
$ServicePrincipalId = $ManagedIdentity.Id  
$AppRoleAssignments = Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $ServicePrincipalId  
$ExchangeOnlinePermissions = $AppRoleAssignments | Where-Object { $_.ResourceId -eq $ExchangeOnlineResourceId }  
if ($ExchangeOnlinePermissions) {  
Write-Output "Managed Identity $($ManagedIdentity.DisplayName) (ID: $($ManagedIdentity.Id)) has Office 365 Exchange Online permissions:"  
$ExchangeOnlinePermissions | Select-Object -Property Id, AppRoleId, PrincipalDisplayName  
Write-Output ""  
}  
}


I assigned User administrator role to the Managed identity:

To retrieve the roles, make use of below script:
$response = $null  
$uri = "[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/transitiveRoleAssignments?`$count=true&`$filter=principalId](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/transitiveRoleAssignments?`$count=true&`$filter=principalId "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/rolemanagement/directory/transitiveroleassignments?`$count=true&`$filter=principalid") eq 'ManagedIdentityServicePrincipalObjID'"  
$method = 'GET'  
$headers = @{'ConsistencyLevel' = 'eventual'}

$response = (Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method $method -Body $null).value


